# "Edit Bot..." button disabled after upgrading Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode-server, xcode-bots, xcode9.3

I've updated my Xcode from 9.2 to 9.3 (It seems to be an issue with later versions as well) and now I'm not able to edit the bots anymore.

[image: Edit Bot button disabled]

What I tried:

- I installed the additional components on the server and local machine that you will be prompted about on first open after updating Xcode.
- I restarted the server and local machine.
- I checked the option "Create and View Bots" on the server. It is set to "logged in users". Just as before the update.
- Everytime I want to open the Xcode Server preference pane in on the local machine in Xcode settings under accounts it gives me an error. When I try it a second time it works though. But it aways fails at the first time:

[image]

- I removed the Xcode Server from the accounts pane and added it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing and adding the server by IP address:

[image]

Then it was possible again to Edit the bot.

[image]

Still strange...

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue by upgrading to XCode 10 today. Fix it by completely shutting down the Mac and restarting.

Comment: XCode -> Preferences -> Server & Bots -> Turn off and Turn on